# The most explicit way of partitioning the reals into two dense subsets with positive measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, real-numbers

In @UmbertoP's [response](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1459762/1176963) to the question, "[Partition of real numbers into dense subsets of positive measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1459263/1176963)," the answer is understandable to a advanced undergraduate; however, I have inadequate knowledge of measure and set theory.

I tried to create a more explicit example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4746783/1176963) but it's too complicated.

**Question:** Is there a more explicit version of Umberto P's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1459762/1176963) that's understandable to an average undergraduate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you'll like this one a bit better.
For simplicity, I'll do my construction for $I = [0,1)$ instead of $\mathbb R$:
to get a partition of $\mathbb R$, just repeat my $A$ and $B$ periodically.

At stage $n$ (for positive integers $n$)
I'll partition $I$ into two sets $A_n$ and $B_n$, each a union of finitely many half-intervals.
Start with $A_1 = [0,1/2)$ and $B_1 = [1/2, 1)$.

Given $A_n$ and $B_n$: for each interval $[a,b)$ in one of these sets of length $s = b-a$,
remove an interval of  length $2^{-n} s$ from the centre of the interval and give it to the other set.  Thus from $[0, 1/2)$ in $A_1$, we remove $[1/8, 3/8)$ and put it in
$B_2$, while $A_2$ keeps $[0,1/8)$ and $[3/8, 1/2)$, and from $[1/2, 1)$ in $B_1$, we remove $[5/8, 7/8)$ and put it in $A_2$, resulting in $A_2 = [0,1/8) \cup [3/8,1/2) \cup [5/8, 7/8)$ and $B_2 = [1/8, 3/8) \cup [1/2, 5/8) \cup [7/8, 1)$.

Note that in going from stage $n$ to stage $n+1$, the measure of the points transferred is $2^{-n}$.  Since $\sum_n 2^{-n}$ is finite, almost every point is transferred only finitely many times.  Since sets of measure $0$ are negligible, I'll define $A$ to consist of the
points that are eventually in $A_n$, and $B$ as its complement the points that
are in $B_n$ for infinitely many $n$, i.e.
$$ A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k, \ B = [0,1) \backslash A = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty B_k$$

Comment: +1 Perhaps there's a nice characterization of this example in terms of binary expansions.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Never mind, $A$ and $B$ don't have equal measure, but what are the measure of the sets?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I’m not sure how to repeat your $A$ and periodically to get [what I want](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747685/what-is-the-measure-of-a-and-b-which-partition-the-reals-into-two-subsets-of). (I placed a +100 bounty on the post.)

Comment: What I mean is $x \in A$ iff $x - \lfloor x \rfloor \in A$.