# What is the asymptotic density and Lebesgue density of two sets which partition the reals into subsets of positive measure?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we partition the reals into two sets $A$ and $B$ that are dense (with positive Lebesgue measure) in every non-empty sub-interval $(a,b)$ of $\mathbb{R}$, where Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ restricts outer measure $\lambda^{*}$ to sets measurable in the [Caratheodory sense](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_criterion).

Does there exist an example (similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747105/the-most-explicit-way-of-partitioning-the-reals-into-two-dense-subsets-with-posi/4747177#4747177)) where both:

$$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\lambda(A\cap [-t,t])/(2t)$$ and $$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\lambda(B\cap [-t,t])/(2t)$$ are greater than zero but neither equal $1/2$?

A bounty is also offered for this question [here](https://matchmaticians.com/questions/kdnngg/kdnngg-what-is-the-asymptotic-density-and-lebesgue-of-a-b).

Comment: For the first question, could you just pick your sets $A$ and $B$ from before and intersect them with the complement of a fat cantor set (do this on $[0,1]$ and translate to get such a set on $\mathbb{R}$) (or some other nowhere dense set with positive measure)? 


Also, does the $A$ and $B$ in this question correspond to the post you linked or to the example you want in question (1)?

Comment: You maybe right about your suggested construction. Could you pleas elaborate further? and Yes, both A and B correspond to those the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

An example satisfying Q1 is as follows:
\begin{align*}
         & A=\left\{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}[3n,3n+2)\setminus D'\right\}\cup D,      \\
         & B=\left\{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}[3n-1,3n)\setminus D\right\}\cup D',      \\
         & D=\{m/2^n\mid n=1,2,\dots,\,m=\pm 1,\pm 2,\dots,\,m/2^n\notin\mathbb{Z}\}, \\
         & D'=\{m/3^n\mid n=1,2,\dots,\,m=\pm 1,\pm 2,\dots,\,m/3^n\notin\mathbb{Z}\}.
    \end{align*}

We can confirm:

- $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}$.
- $A$ and $B$ are dense in any open interval $(a,b)$ since $D\subset A$, $\bar{D}=\mathbb{R}$ and $D'\subset B$, $\bar{D'}=\mathbb{R}$. Here, for  $X\subset \mathbb{R}$, $\bar{X}$ represents the closure of $X$ under the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$. Note that $D$ means binary approximation and $D'$ means ternary approximation, and $D$ and $D'$ do not intersect.
- We have
  \begin{align*}
      \frac{\lambda(A\cap [-3n,3n])}{2\cdot 3n}
      &= \frac{2n\cdot 2}{6n}=\frac{2}{3}, \qquad n=1,2,\dots
  \end{align*}
  then it follows that
  \begin{align*}
      \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\lambda(A\cap [-t,t])}{2t}
      &= \frac{2}{3}\neq \frac{1}{2}.
  \end{align*}
  By the same manner as above, we see also
  \begin{align*}
      \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\lambda(B\cap[-t,t])}{2t}=\frac{1}{3}\neq \frac{1}{2}.
  \end{align*}

Q2: The way of giving meaning is up to you.
I'd consider it as normalization over $2ε=λ(B_\varepsilon(x))$, and I would answer that it's the probability of a number chosen from a uniform distribution on $B_\varepsilon(x)$ being contained in $A$ (or $B$). 
I have no idea of another interpretation. Other people may have different answers.

Comment: Thank you su much. If you are interested, a bounty is offered here:  https://matchmaticians.com/questions/kdnngg/kdnngg-what-is-the-asymptotic-density-and-lebesgue-of-a-b